# Reference file in higher directory?

Tags: php

My file structure is like this:

```
filethatineed.html
folder
    index.php
```

In index.php, I want to reference the HTML file.

Here's what I'd have if it were in the same directory:

```
<?php include('filethatineed.html');?>
```

How could i change this to include the file when it's in the higher directory?

Comment: `<?php include('../filethatineed.html');?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php include('../filethatineed.html');?>
```

`..` means "one directory above".

Comment: What if it were 2 directories above? Would it be `../../`?

Comment: And what if it were getting ridiculous so you wanted to start at the home directory?

Comment: You could count the number of jumps up the hierarchy, or just point to an absolute path, ie `/path/to/your/folder/filethatineed.html`. Note that the file/path must be accessible by the user scope that php is executing under.

Comment: Alright. 1 last thing. It's finding the file just fine, but now the images and css file referenced by filethatineed.html, which are present and work when it's all in the same directory, aren't working. I can see all the text of that file, and "missing image" images. Do i need to reference them differently, if the file will be included from somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, you need to point the images and css to an absolute path. Say your css is under `media/css/styles.css` you should change it into `//yourdomain/media/css/styles.css` if the html is to be included from different places.

Answer (score 1):

Use `include('../filethatineed.html')`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use relative path pattern
like
For file just above your current folder then

`<?php include('../filethatineed.html');?`>

Answer (score 1):

There are following ways to include file

```
1. include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/filethatineed.html");
2. include(__DIR__."../filethatineed.html");
3. include('../filethatineed.html');
```