# Included file from another directory can't locate CSS file or images?

Tags: php, html, css

I asked [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19027495/reference-file-in-higher-directory) about how to reference a file in a higher directory, and the answer is:

```
<?php include('../filethatineed.html');?>
```

The problem now is that filethatineed.html can't find it's CSS file. If it's in the same directory as my file that includes it, this works fine. But when it and it's reference files are moved to a different directory, those files can't be located anymore. Opening filethatineed.html in a web browser displays it correctly, so the files are in the correct place.

Here's how I reference them currently, as an example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="header_style.css">
```

How should I reference them differently to make sure they work when the file is included from another directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference them by using an absolute or root-relative path.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="header_style.css">
```

**Either** (absolute, protocol-less):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//yourdomain/path/to/css/header_style.css">
```

**or** (root-relative):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path/to/css/header_style.css">
```

Comment: The header_style.css file is located directly in the public_html folder. Could i refer to it without referring to the domain name?

Comment: try using `href="/header_style.css"` <- note the `/`

Answer (score 1):

You will have to set CSS and image paths according to file in which you are using  `<?php include('../filethatineed.html');?>` not to that file that you are including.
OR you can use this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//example.com/path/to/image/img.jpg" />
```

Comment: The header_style.css file is located directly in the public_html folder. Could i refer to it without referring to the domain name?

Comment: use complete path to file and this will be included anywhere you want.

Comment: path href="www.example.com/path/to/css/your_css.css"

Answer (score 1):

You need to give full path of header_style.css
example

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://foo.com/css/header_style.css">
```

or whatever your path is.

Answer (score 0):

The client (= the browser) doesn't see nor care whether your HTML comes from an `include()` or not. All paths will be relative to the directory of the HTML file that the browser is currently pointing to. Hence, any relative paths you use in `filethatineed.html` will no longer work.

You'd have to use absolute paths as suggested by Alasjo, or change the relative paths.